# pandas dataframe - groupby dataframe by datetime (last 12 months) and agreeing two columns, the answer to be like that ↓

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Grouping the data frames by the month that are saved in the "date" field, and agreeing two columns, respectively "wealth_avg" and "state_money_avg"

what I have: df
[image]

what I expected:
[image]

recap: i expect an array with 12 objects, where each object has the number of months: 1 meaning January, 2 means February and so on, and "wealth_avg" that are the avg of the wealth   and "state_money_avg" that are the avg of the state_money, all this being calculated from that dateframe grouped by month.

- months that are not in the data frame must be null/nan (doesn't matter which one, preferably null) when we return the result

simple code ex:

```
import pandas as pd

# intialise data of lists.
data = {
        'name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack', 'alexander'],
        'age':[20, 20, 20, 20, 20],
        'date':["2002-01-02", "2002-12-10", "2002-01-01", "2002- 
03-01", "2002-10-09"],
        'wealth': [500, 100, 400, 200, 300],
        'state_money': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
    }

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Print the output.
df
```

Comment: please share the code you're using. also `pd.pivot_table()` might be helpful

Comment: @mitoRibo shared the code. This is a simple dataframe example

Comment: thanks for sharing! please add the code for what you have tried so far. where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @mitoRibo I didn't necessarily try anything using the pandas library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming** `date` column's type is **datetime**, you can extract months to a different column:

```
df["month"] = df["date"].dt.month
```

Then group by `month` column and find the averages:

```
df.groupby("month").agg(wealth_avg=("wealth", "mean"), state_money_avg=("state_money", "mean"))
```